# Locking files when sharing a working copy with SVN

Tags: svn, asp-classic, locking, file-access

I know that this is not the suggested way of doing things with SVN, but I would like not to change our current way of working with our classic ASP application.

Everything is centralized on a single IIS development server and I don't want every developer to have their own copy.

Having said that, is there a way to use locking when sharing a working copy under SVN?

From what I understood, you can lock files on the repository so no one can commit them, but what about concurrent access in the working directory?

Answer (score 1):

The locking is not available thru SVN on a Working copy. This is kind of a vague concept of using a repository and still having a common area where all developers are working!

I would suggest you to change the working methodology and let the developers have their own copies, and on the IIS working copy, use update (or auto-update) as soon as a change is checked in. You can use Pollers to look for  changes in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sharing the working copy, then it is basically just a bunch of files and folders and you "lock" them using standard filesystem permissions.

Comment: From what you know, is there a way to manage this automatically using SVN hooks?